# How to remove function name from element with blur event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this issue and till now I didn't find the solution to this

This is the code

`<input type="text" id="myid" onblur="myfunction(); myfunction2();" >`

And after an ajax response like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    url: 'my_url',
    data: { info: data},
    datatype: 'json',

    success: function(res) {

        if (!res.error) {

            //Remove myfunction2() from my input element
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to remove from the `onblur` the function called `myfunction2()`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `$('#myid').attr('onblur', 'myfunction();');` <== Please don't do this. Learn `$('#myid').on('click', ...)` syntax

Comment: What is your intent to remove  myfunction2() and, what is the intend with the ajax call. Could you explain a little bit more.

Comment: @FrankerZ yeah i know about `.on('click'...` but this this code is from a file made by other person and im trying to do what they asked me

Comment: @JPRLCol because `myfunction2()` have a validation and it needs to be removed if there is not error in the ajax call response

Comment: @Ashe I assume your myfunction() is the one who do the ajax call the you want myFunction2 to be callbock for the ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#myid").attr("onblur", "");`, however, this is rather poor practice.

You should instead do this:

`$("#myid").on("blur", "myFunctionGoesHere(params);");` to add

`$("#myid").off("blur", "#myid", "myFunctionToRemove()");` to remove